# Storing a column value while doing awk group by

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have an input file with data as follows:

```
1484523745 96000 2856 25059 0  
1484523745 96000 2856 25150 0  
1484523745 4864960 2856 997962 193  
1484523745 96000 2856 24923 1  
1484523745 280000 2856 61454 12  
1484523746 1179968 2856 309430 1  
1484523746 4864960 2856 1115576 300  
1484523746 96000 2856 25059 0  
1484523746 4864960 2856 997962 116  
1484523746 96000 2856 25059 0  
1484523746 96000 2856 25059 0  
1484523746 4864960 2856 1146028 211  
1484523746 4864960 2856 1115576 371  
1484523746 3184960 2856 875340 1
```

The requirement is to find the aggregate of columns 4 and 5 based on unique combination of columns 2 and 3, finding the count of each unique combination and showing this result with the value of column 1 (epoch time) for the first occurrence of each unique combination. So the output should look like this:

```
96000 2856 150309 1 6 1484523745  
3184960 2856 875340 1 1 1484523746  
1179968 2856 309430 1 1 1484523746  
280000 2856 61454 12 1 1484523745  
4864960 2856 5373104 1191 5 1484523745
```

This was easily done in my Mac PC with a one liner command using datamash:

```
datamash -W --sort -g 2,3 sum 4,5 count 5 first 1 < inputfile
```

However, the Linux production server where the input files are present does not have datamash and installation access is restricted. (There are thousands of input files, so I can't FTP them to my Mac). So I am trying to achieve the same with awk command. I have achieved the required result except for printing the value of column 1 for first occurrence of unique combination:

```
awk -F " " '{a[$2" "$3]+=$4; b[$2" "$3]+=$5; c[$2" "$3]++} END{for(i in a)print i, a[i], b[i], c[i]}' inputfile
```

Using `awk`, How to store the value of column 1 for the first occurrence of each unique combination of columns 2 and 3?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: you may also consider installing locally `datamash` from the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for the presence of a key in an array, and only update on non-presence:

```
{
    if (! ($2" "$3 in x))
        x[$2" "$3] = $1;
    a[$2" "$3]+=$4;
    b[$2" "$3]+=$5;
    c[$2" "$3]++
}
END {
    for (i in a)
        print i, a[i], b[i], c[i], x[i]
}
```